# How to specify Admin area while using authentication in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-areas

This question may be asked before but I googled a lot about tutorial providing the simple description of the security implementation in MVC4 with area. My concern is this, I have two areas in my application which are named as Admin and Public. Now I want that if someone tries to access Admin pages then he first faces the login page then once credentials are verified user can view admin pages. Now I have implemented default authentication template of ASP which lets me access admin pages with/without login. So for the sake of security I had provided

```
[Authorize()]
```

with all pages which I want to secure now this process is working but still there is a problem that it is giving me following error [image]

Now I don't want my public area to be secure so how can I make it specific to Admin area only. And I want besides showing

> unauthorized access

how can I make it to redirect on the login page as it used to happen in traditional asp.net application. I have made following changes in root web.config file.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Areas/Admin/Account/Index"/>
</authentication>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the area routing in the arearegistration. Please remember to add the namespace in there

Comment: It is already there but result is same.
For Admin
context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_default",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new {controller="Account",action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "myNS.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
            );
For Public 
context.MapRoute(
                "Public_default",
                "Public/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new {action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new[] { "myNS.Areas.Public.Controllers" }
            );